# htaccess redirect to external website without changing address bar

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect

I have a subdoman called, let's say:

```
cloud.mygizmo.com
```

But when someone navigates to this URL I want them to actually go to:

```
11.22.33.44/cloud
```

Which is on a completely different host from `mygizmo.com` and can't be moved.

In my `.htaccess` I have this:

```
RewriteEngine on
# Use PHP5.4 as default
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php54 .php
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^cloud\.mygizmo\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.cloud\.mygizmo\.com$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "http\:\/\/11\.22\.33\44\/cloud" [L]
```

Which does do the redirect, but it still changes the address bar in the user's browser.

How do I make it so that if a user navigates to `cloud.mygizmo.com` they actually go to `11.22.33.44/cloud` but the address bar still says `cloud.mygizmo.com`?

Comment: I'm not a DNS guy, but couldn't you accomplish this by adding or modifying an A record?

Comment: @Tim:  Well, I can't add an A record to point to a folder eg `11.22.33.44/cloud`.  But I suppose I could point it to `11.22.33.44` and then add a redirect there.  But then won't the URL still change to `11.22.33.44`?

Comment: sorry, don't know. I was just throwing that out there. i've seen domains do this before, and I can't remember if they're were parked domains or not... for example, you'd go to adobbe.com and get redirected to adobe.com, yet your address bar still shows adobbe.com. unfortunately I don't remember what that's called. That's just an example, Guys, I know Adobe doesn't do that - don't flame me :)

Comment: @Tim:  Thanks for the suggestion nonetheless.

Answer (score 1):

You can't. Redirection doesn't work like that.

You could *proxy* the data instead (which would be inefficient and increase your bandwidth costs).

Comment: I've edited my question to be a little less specific.  I don't care if I use redirects, proxies or unicorns.  I'm really just looking for an end result.

Answer (score 1):

If you have mod_proxy installed, you can use the `P` flag to reverse proxy on behalf of the browser:

```
RewriteEngine on
# Use PHP5.4 as default
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php54 .php
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^cloud\.mygizmo\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.cloud\.mygizmo\.com$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "http\:\/\/11\.22\.33\44\/cloud" [L,P]
```

You can also reverse proxy using `ProxyPass` or `ProxyPassMatch` but those will only work in the vhost/server config.

In the `cloud.mygizmo.com`/`www.cloud.mygizmo.com` vhost you can say:

```
ProxyPass / http://11.22.33.44/cloud
```

And then any request for the `cloud.mygizmo.com` gets proxied to the `http://11.22.33.44/cloud` host.

Note that `ProxyPass` works like `Redirect`, it links together the path nodes `/` and `/cloud`. So if someone were to go to:

```
http://cloud.mygizmo.com/foo/bar
```

They'd get reverse proxied to:

```
http://11.22.33.44/cloud/foo/bar
```

If that's not what you want, then use `ProxyPassMatch`:

```
ProxyPassMatch ^/$ http://11.22.33.44/cloud
```

Alternatively, if you want the rewrite rule to behave in the same way, you need to capture the request URI and pass it to the target with a backreference:

```
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ http://11.22.33.44/cloud/$1 [L,P]
```

Comment: This sounds perfect.  I don't really care if I use redirects, proxies, or sprinkles -- I'm really just interested in the end results.  When you say "In the [...] vhost you can say..."  do you mean in the `.htaccess` file on `cloud.mygizmo.com`?

Comment: @JohnDibling by vhost config, I mean the config file that defines the site "cloud.mygizmo.com", not the htaccess file (which will not allow `ProxyPass` directives).

Comment: Ah.  Hmm.  I don't know if I have access to that.  This is a site hosted at bluehost.

Comment: @JohnDibling Probably not, you'll have to use mod_rewrite and the `P` flag. But it may be that Bluehost doesn't have mod_proxy loaded at all. If `P` flag doesn't do anything (e.g. it redirects instead of proxy, or nothing at all), then mod_proxy isn't loaded and you'll have to use a script proxy through php or something.

Answer (score 1):

probably not the ideal solution, but you *could* build a page that's pretty much a giant iframe and load the content inside the iframe...

Edit: See if Blue Host allows Parked Domains in your control panel (aka Masked Forward). I think this is what you want.

Comment: Well that's generally a nice pragmatic idea, but I don't think I'm going to do that. :)

Comment: throwing stuff against the wall... :)